# Android asyncTask hanging the view

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've `AsyncTask` calling **Web Service**. The whole view hangs until the task finished in the background. I need to make the view not hanging like this.

```
    public ArrayList bindListView() {
    ArrayList listViewItems = null;
    try {
        listViewItems = new NewsPage.GetNews(getActivity(),lastid).execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listViewItems;
}

private class GetNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList> {
    Activity activity;

    public GetNews(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<NewsListItem> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        Log.i("xxxxy", lastid + "");
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + lastid);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray news = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < news.length(); i++) {

                    NewsListItem newsitem = new NewsListItem();
                    JSONObject c = news.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = c.getString("title");
                    String excerpt = c.getString("excerpt");
                    String imageUrl = c.getString("thumbnailURL");
                    imageUrl = genurl + imageUrl;
                    newsitem.title = title;
                    newsitem.content = excerpt;
                    newsitem.imageUrl = imageUrl;
                    newsitem.id = c.getString("id");
                    newsList.add(newsitem);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {

            }
        } else {
        }
        return newsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code..

Comment: post your code please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute` to return the list of NewsListItems. In the example I am assuming that `listViewItems` is a class member in your activity. After the webservice call new items are added to the list. All you have to do is make sure that the list adapter (I assume you are using a `ListView`) knows where to find the list elements, and that you notify it of the changes.

Calling `new NewsPage.GetNews(lastid).execute();` starts the request asynchronously, so the UI will not hang.

```
public void fetchNewsListItems() {
    new NewsPage.GetNews(lastid).execute();
}

private class GetNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList> {
    int lastid;

    public GetNews(int lastid) {
        this.lastid = lastid;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<NewsListItem> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        Log.i("xxxxy", lastid + "");
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + lastid);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray news = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < news.length(); i++) {

                    NewsListItem newsitem = new NewsListItem();
                    JSONObject c = news.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = c.getString("title");
                    String excerpt = c.getString("excerpt");
                    String imageUrl = c.getString("thumbnailURL");
                    imageUrl = genurl + imageUrl;
                    newsitem.title = title;
                    newsitem.content = excerpt;
                    newsitem.imageUrl = imageUrl;
                    newsitem.id = c.getString("id");
                    newsList.add(newsitem);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {

            }
        } else {
        }
        return newsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        listViewItems.addAll(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `get` makes it synchronous, defeating the whole purpose of using `AsyncTask`.  Whatever needs to be done when the background work is complete should be done inside `onPostExecute`.  If the `AsyncTask` holds a reference to the `Activity`, make sure the `Activity` cancels the `AsyncTask` when it's paused or destroyed.

By the way, it's completely pointless to override methods just to have them call super, as you've done here with `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`.